# gdb RuntimeError: pretty-printer already registered: libstdc++-v6

Tags: python, gdb, codeblocks

I'm using Code::Blocks and want to have gdb python-enabled. So I followed the C::B wiki http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Pretty_Printers to configure it.

My pp.gdb is the same as that in the wiki except that I replace the path with my path to printers.py.

```
python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-builds/x32-4.8.1-posix-dwarf-rev3/mingw32/share/gcc-4.8.1/python/libstdcxx/v6')
from printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
end
```

Then I tested it:

```
(gdb) source C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-builds\x32-4.8.1-posix-dwarf-rev3\mingw32\bin\pp.gdb
```

And the error message showed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-builds/x32-4.8.1-posix-dwarf-rev3/mingw32/
  share/gcc-4.8.1/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py", line 911, in register_libstdcxx_printers
    gdb.printing.register_pretty_printer(obj, libstdcxx_printer)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\mingw-builds\x32-4.8.1-posix-dwarf-rev3\mingw32\
  share\gdb/python/gdb/printing.py", line 146, in register_pretty_printer
    printer.name)
RuntimeError: pretty-printer already registered: libstdc++-v6
C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-builds\x32-4.8.1-posix-dwarf-rev3\mingw32\bin\pp.gd
b:6: Error in sourced command file:
Error while executing Python code.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You probably need a raw string or forward slashes in your path.

Comment: @Wooble Yes, you are right. I didn't notice the wiki use forward slash in sys.path.insert, although it uses back slash in the source clause. But after that, new problem appeared. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 6):

Today, I also see this similar issue, after I update my libstdcxx's pretty from an old gcc4.7.x version to the gcc's trunk HEAD version to fix some other problems.

I'm also using Codeblocks, and I have those two lines in my customized gdb script.

```
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
```

Note that I already have `-nx` option parssed to gdb when it started. After tweak for a while, I found that the libstdcxx's pretty printer is automatically loaded and get registered after the `from...import...` line. So, as a solution, you can just comment out the second line, and everything works just fine here.

```
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
#register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
```

Also, I think the GDB's official wiki [STLSupport - GDB Wiki](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport) and Codeblocks' officical wiki [Pretty Printers - CodeBlocks](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Pretty_Printers) should be updated to state this issue.

EDIT:
I just see the file: libstdcxx\v6__init__.py from GCC svn trunk(maybe, it was added recently), and I see it has code:

```
# Load the pretty-printers.
from printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
register_libstdcxx_printers(gdb.current_objfile())
```

So, I think this code will automatically register the printers, so you don't need explicitly call `register_libstdcxx_printers (None)`.

Comment: I just refine the answer since I see `libstdcxx\v6__init__.py` already register the printers(GCC SVN HEAD)

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need to have this code.  It seems like the libstdc++ prnters are preloaded -- which is normal in many setups... we designed printers to "just work", and the approach of using python code to explicitly load printers was a transitional thing.

One way to check is to run gdb -nx, start your C++ program, and then use "info pretty-printer".

Comment: (1)You are right, there's a gdbinit file in the etc folder which gdb reads at startup, and the content of this file is essentially the same as my pp.gdb. So I don't need pp.gdb at all. (2)But there's still problem, if I print a vector<string> v, it works fine; if I print v[0], then get "error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x29a2ca50". Maybe I should ask it in a new page? Because it not relevant with this one.

Comment: I have asked it as a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295199/simple-code-cause-error-reading-variable-cannot-access-memory-at-address)

Answer (score 0):

If you got this error `RuntimeError: pretty-printer already registered: libstdc++-v6` that's mean that you don't need to do anything mentioned in [C::B wiki](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Pretty_Printers).
You can just uncheck `Disable startup scripts (-nx)` option under: `Codeblocks->Settings->Debugger->Default` and that's it.