# Simple code cause error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I am trying to use a python-enabled gdb [MinGW-builds](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/). And I run into an error. This is a rather simple code, and It works fine when debugging under MSVC.

```
D:\CppProject\c1\bin\Debug>gdb c1.exe
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6
(copyright, license, bug report, etc omitted here)
Reading symbols from D:\CppProject\c1\bin\Debug\c1.exe...done.
(gdb) l
1       #include <iostream>
2       #include <vector>
3
4       using namespace std;
5
6       int main()
7       {
8           vector<string> v;
9           v.push_back("first");
10          v.push_back("second");
(gdb)
11          cout<<v[0]<<endl;
12          cout<<v[1]<<endl;
13
14          return 0;
15      }
(gdb) break 11
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4016c9: file D:\CppProject\c1\main.cpp, line 11.
(gdb) run
Starting program: D:\CppProject\c1\bin\Debug\c1.exe
[New Thread 1256.0xbe8]

Breakpoint 1, main () at D:\CppProject\c1\main.cpp:11
11          cout<<v[0]<<endl;
(gdb) p v
$1 = std::vector of length 2, capacity 2 = {"first", "second"}
(gdb) p v[0]
$2 = <error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x29a2ca50>
```

Comment: Not sure if this has any effect at all, but you should `#include <string>`

Comment: @ColonelPanic No difference, the gdb error still happened.

Comment: I find gdb on Windows very unreliable. More often than not it just hangs on me at a random moment, and I have to go to the task manager to kill it.

Comment: I just tested your code, it is fine under "GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-48.el6)" environment. The value of v[0] is printed correctly.

Comment: @JohnSmith I tested it under CentOS 6.4 gdb 7.2-60.e16_4.1, it also works fine. I wonder if this problem is Windows specific, or MinGW-builds&Win7 specific?

Comment: @n.m. Did you ever encounter my problem under Windows?

Comment: I think so but don't remember exactly. Gdb is so flakey under Windows I have stopped using it. I can try to reproduce it.

Comment: I could not reproduce it on the cygwin build of gdb (it hangs all the time), but the mingw build reproduces it. Python does not play a role here, it's the `operator[]` that cannot be evaluated correctly. You should not rely on `gdb` being able to call `operator[]` anyway; if it's never instantiated in your program, or always inlined, there's no `operator[]` as far as gdb is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

This may sound basic - did you compile with -O0 ? I suspect that compiler optimization might cause your trouble.

Comment: this was a life saver. Recompiled my library without optimization and I was able to read the contents of every member variable, even private ones.